# Running a CKFetchRecordsOperation while in UIApplicationStateBackground

Tags: ios, core-data, background-process, cloudkit, remote-notifications

My app is setup to receive CloudKit remote notifications. Sometimes it receives these notifications while it is running in the background. I have not done anything with these notifications yet - I have simply passed UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData to the completion handler. The reason is that I didn't think I could simply download from CloudKit while in the background - I thought that could only be done via Background Fetch or setting up a special job to run in the background. But I am revisiting this now, and I see that running the CKFetchRecordsOperation and downloading the related CKAsset file while in UIApplicationStateBackground actually does seem to work.

So my current code is this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    __ENTERING_METHOD__
    CKNotification *ckNotification = [CKNotification notificationFromRemoteNotificationDictionary:userInfo];
    if (ckNotification) {
        if ([ckNotification.subscriptionID isEqualToString:kCKDocumentChangeSubscription]) {
            CKRecordID *recordID = [(CKQueryNotification*)ckNotification recordID];
            if (recordID) {
                if([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {

                    if (completionHandler) {
                        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    CKFetchRecordsOperation *fetchRecordsOperation = [[CKFetchRecordsOperation alloc] initWithRecordIDs:@[recordID]];
                    fetchRecordsOperation.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock = ^(NSDictionary *recordsByRecordID, NSError *error) {

                        if (error) {
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                if (completionHandler) {
                                    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            CKRecord *ckDocumentRecord = recordsByRecordID[recordID];
                            CKAsset *documentAsset = [ckDocumentRecord objectForKey:ckDocumentAsset];
                            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:documentAsset.fileURL];
                            [self handleData:data];

                            UIBackgroundFetchResult result = (data == nil)?UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed:UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData;
                            if (completion) {
                                completion(result);
                            }
                        }

                    };
                    CKContainer *defaultContainer = [CKContainer defaultContainer];
                    CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [defaultContainer publicCloudDatabase];
                    [publicDatabase addOperation:fetchRecordsOperation];
                }
            }
            else {
                if (completionHandler) {
                    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (completionHandler) {
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
        }
    }
}
```

And I want this code to be this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    __ENTERING_METHOD__
    CKNotification *ckNotification = [CKNotification notificationFromRemoteNotificationDictionary:userInfo];
    if (ckNotification) {
        if ([ckNotification.subscriptionID isEqualToString:kCKDocumentChangeSubscription]) {
            CKRecordID *recordID = [(CKQueryNotification*)ckNotification recordID];
            if (recordID) {
                CKFetchRecordsOperation *fetchRecordsOperation = [[CKFetchRecordsOperation alloc] initWithRecordIDs:@[recordID]];
                fetchRecordsOperation.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock = ^(NSDictionary *recordsByRecordID, NSError *error) {

                    if (error) {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            if (completionHandler) {
                                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        CKRecord *ckDocumentRecord = recordsByRecordID[recordID];
                        CKAsset *documentAsset = [ckDocumentRecord objectForKey:ckDocumentAsset];
                        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:documentAsset.fileURL];
                        [self handleData:data];

                        UIBackgroundFetchResult result = (data == nil)?UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed:UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData;
                        if (completion) {
                            completion(result);
                        }
                    }

                };
                CKContainer *defaultContainer = [CKContainer defaultContainer];
                CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [defaultContainer publicCloudDatabase];
                [publicDatabase addOperation:fetchRecordsOperation];
            }
            else {
                if (completionHandler) {
                    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (completionHandler) {
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
        }
    }
}
```

Does running a CKFetchRecordsOperation and downloading the related CKAsset file while in the background constitute any sort of a violation of what can (or SHOULD) be done in the background?

Comment: CKAssets are used to store large files (Apple recommends anything more than a few kilobytes in size, but no more than 250MB) in iCloud and associate them with specific CKRecords.

When downloading a record with a CKAsset, the asset’s data is temporarily saved to disk, but it is not guaranteed to stay there long, and may be cleaned up when the system needs to free memory. So it is definitely a good idea to get the data from the asset as soon as the record is downloaded. The file can be accessed from the asset’s fileURL property.